# Insert character after each 8 character

Tags: php, string, text, binary, character

i have one string called `dvojka` value is `0110111101101010` It's a binary.
And I need to insert character "-" after each 8 chracter, because one character is 8 bits.
Is there some way using PHP?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) ?

```
$output = wordwrap($dvojka,8,'-',true);
```

The 3rd parameter is required as the string your breaking up doesn't have any whitespace

Example : http://codepad.org/sbhBe5pb

Comment: Oh, thats better than first one.. I will accept this one.
Once again. thank you